# No module error in Python 3.6 with Click library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a CLI in python by using the package `click`. The Python version I'm using is `3.6`

This is the main of my application:

```
import os
import click

cmd_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'commands')


class IAMCLI(click.MultiCommand):

    def list_commands(self, ctx):
        rv = []
        for filename in os.listdir(cmd_folder):
            if filename.endswith('.py') and \
                    filename.startswith('cmd_'):
                rv.append(filename[4:-3])
        rv.sort()
        return rv

    def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
        ns = {}
        fn = os.path.join(cmd_folder, 'cmd_{}.py'.format(cmd_name))
        with open(fn) as f:
            code = compile(f.read(), fn, 'exec')
            eval(code, ns, ns)
        return ns['cli']


@click.command(cls=IAMCLI)
@click.option('--env', default='dev', type=click.Choice(['dev', 'staging', 'production']),
              help='AWS Environment')
@click.pass_context
def cli():
    """AWS IAM roles and policies management CLI."""
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

and this is the tree:

```
├── cli
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── aws
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── policy.py
│   │   └── role.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   └── commands
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── cmd_dump.py
```

the `cmd_dump.py` looks like this:

```
import click

from cli.aws.role import fetch_roles


@click.command('dump', short_help='Dump IAM resources')
@click.pass_context
def cli():
  pass
```

the problem is that when I try to run `python cli/cli.py --help` this is what I get:

```
File "cli/commands/cmd_dump.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cli.aws.role import fetch_roles
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cli.aws'; 'cli' is not a package
```

Any idea about that?

Comment: The parent directory of `cli.py` is prepended to `sys.path`, so you're trying to import `aws.role.fetch_roles` from your cli.py script.

Comment: You mean here right `os.path.join(cmd_folder, 'cmd_{}.py'.format(cmd_name))`?

Comment: Not clear how to fix it. any idea?

Comment: Your directory and one of your files are both named `cli`.  Rename these to something else.  Looks like that sort of problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will try to give another answer based on my approach when starting development of a new python project. Do you plan to distribute your project, or maybe just share it with someone? If you do, what do you think - will this someone be happy with needing to remember the command

```
$ python path/to/project/codebase/cli/cli.py --help
```

to use your tool? Wouldn't it be easier for him to remember the command

```
$ cli --help
```

instead?

I suggest you to start with packaging of your project right away - write a minimal setup script:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mypkg',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['click'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['cli=cli.cli:cli'],
    },
)
```

You can always enhance your setup script when new requirements emerge. Place the setup script in the root directory of your codebase:

```
├── setup.py
├── cli
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── aws
...
```

Now run `python setup.py develop` or even better, `pip install --editable=.`<sup>1</sup> from the codebase root directory (where the `setup.py`script is). You have installed your project in the development mode and now can invoke

```
$ cli --help
```

with all the imports being resolved correctly (which would resolve your issue). But you gain much more besides that - you gain a way to package your project to be ready to be distributed to your target users and a clean command line interface which your users will invoke the same way as you just did.

Now continue with the project development. If you change the code of the `cli` command, it will be applied on the fly so you don't need to reinstall the project each time you change anything.

Once you are ready with the project development and want to deliver it to your users, issue:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This will package your project into a installable `wheel` file (you will need to install `wheel` package to be able to invoke the command: `pip install wheel --user`). Usually it will reside in the `dist` subdirectory of the codebase root dir. Give this file to the user. To install the file, he will issue

```
$ pip install Downloads/mypkg-0.1-py3-none.whl --user
```

and can start tp use your tool right away:

```
$ cli --help
```

This is a very much simplified description and there is a lot of stuff to learn, but there is also a ton of helpful materials to guide you through the process.

If you want to learn more about the topic: as a quickstart reference, I would recommend the excellent [PyPA packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/). For packaging `click` commands, [their own docs are more than sufficient](http://click.pocoo.org/5/setuptools/).

---

1. I would encourage you to use `pip` for distribution and packaging development where applicable as it is a standard tool for that.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. The point that the command `python path/to/project/codebase/cli/cli.py --help` doesn't resolve correctly the modules

Comment: Yes, because you are calling it as a plain script via the interpreter. The approach I described is to call the command line utilities as they are meant to be called, thus avoiding the headache when treating them as python scripts.

Comment: Note that I didn't need to change your project structure at all. No renaming, no moving files around.

Comment: I would also encourage you to quickly read the notes in this regard in `click`s docs I mentioned in my answer (http://click.pocoo.org/5/setuptools/). The 3rd point applies to your project already, although it is not that large yet.

Comment: yep I saw that points but the my point is that when you develop locally and you make changes to the project then you need to run every time `python setup.py develop` in order to apply the changes

Comment: That's the opposite of what I wrote: "If you change the code of the cli command, it will be applied on the fly so **you don't need to reinstall the project each time you change anything**."

Comment: That's the way to create a tool with a command line interface. As for "Refactoring would be a nightmare if you use pip for every single package" - what do you mean? Pip is used to distribute your **project**, not each one of the packages in the project separately.

Comment: I still don' get it - so how exactly does my answer prevent you from stepping down a project to just a package and losing time checking import errors?

Comment: Hmm, sure, that's an issue, but it is a general issue independent of whether you are packaging or not. Let's take your answer as an example - does it protect you against extracting `aws` package in a separate project? The refactoring overhead is the same, or am I leaving something out?

Answer (score 1):

Do not run scripts inside packages! Packages are made to be imported in code but not to run scripts inside them. The rest is non related with import errors.

For example:

```
├── cli # package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── aws
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── policy.py
│   │   └── role.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   │   └── commands
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── cmd_dump.py 
├── run_this_module.py
```

Module to execute `run_this_module.py`:

```
import cli

"""Do your code here"""
```

Comment: the point to run `click` in this way is that it breaks the execution. by running `python main.py dump` I get the following error `TypeError: cli() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: I use these simple rule (and a lot of other rules) to simplify my work in software development. Python is a language I use to design software not for production. It takes me some copy and paste commands to translate it in pure C language and I am done.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a hundred times.  It is tempting to name a package the same thing at multiple levels, but resist!  I tend to have `__main__.py` in my packages these days, which helps solve the problem that you are having.

I suspect you are having a namespace issue.  Try renaming your package or the internal file called `cli.py`.  Be sure to refactor any imports that are attempting to use these.

Also, change your function name to something besides `cli`.  Same issue.

```
├── cli                    <- rename this to 'my_app' or something else
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── aws
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── policy.py
│   │   └── role.py
│   ├── cli.py             <- or maybe it is easier to rename this
│   └── commands
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── cmd_dump.py
```

Comment: Why this? What should I achieve by renaming it?

Comment: When you get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cli.aws'; 'cli' is not a package`, it is actually looking inside your `cli.py`, NOT the directory `cli` as you think it is.  That is why the module is not found... it isn't looking at the module!  The odd thing is, sometimes it will work, and sometimes it won't, depending on the order that cpython creates them.  Just avoid naming things the same across the board.

Comment: I've renamed the folder aws_iam_cli and it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok, when you renamed, did you also refactor your imports?  `from aws_iam_cli.aws.role import fetch_roles`?

Comment: My import looks like from aws_iam_cli.provider.role import fetch_role is it wrong?

Comment: Based on your file structure, I suspect that it is.  Your error in the question was in `cli/commands/cmd_dump.py` and the error was `from cli.aws.role import fetch_roles`.  That is where I'm getting your paths from.  You would know what that line is better than I.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157798/discussion-between-slightlynybbled-and-mazzy).

Comment: Change your function name to something besides `cli` as well.  Same namespace issue.  I edited my answer.