# Python, modules, importError

Tags: python, import

I have a problem while importing class from another package. Unfortunately importError occurs. I will enclose project structure to visualize my problem. Import error occurs when adding 'import A' statement.

Class 'Derived' and 'Base' are placed in folder called 'folder'

```
from folder.Derived import Derived
class A:
   pass

import A
#The line above causes importError
class Base:
   pass

from folder.Base import Base
class Derived(Base):
   pass
```

Comment: You are importing class A while you have it? You do not need to import it!

Comment: I dont have it in the same folder, class A is above class Derived and Base in project structure. Even ide says that i have to import that class.

Comment: Do me a favor. Read your question aloud. Will you understand anything?

Comment: Yes, I included sample project structure which visualize my project structure. In my opinion it is clear what is written here. I wrote even which line causes the error.

Comment: In your comment you did say: `class A is above class Derived and Base in project structure`. Define `above`. Where above? You may see an example in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46889031/2430448) for how to show project's structure.

Answer (score 0):

You cant import A from A because you don't have A. if A is in Derived use:

```
 from Derived import A
```